# Copy custom emoji to clipboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I want to make an application like emoji icons available in the app store. For that I need to put custom emoji images which can be used in other social networking applications like skype,fb,what'sapp etc. Image can be copied using IUPasteboard.

I have tried following code to copy the image

```
  [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image = imgView.image;
```

And this code successfully copy the image and it can be retrieved in the same application in the UIImage as

```
  UIImage *image = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
```

But my question is that how it can be pasted in the UITextField of the other apps from where the user types the message.

And does it works in IOS 6 and IOS 5 ??? (I m working on Xcode 4.5.1).

If it is possible to copy emoji and can be pasted in the textfield than please help me with some code or provide some link.

Answer (score 3):

Every `emoji` has `unicode`. Now specify each image with unique emoji's unicode

While pasting check like this:

```
  if([UIImagePNGRepresentation(pasteBoardImage) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(emojiImage)]) //as emoji image has unique unicode
  {
      //add emoji based upon image
      NSString *myString = txtField.text;
      //For example image you are going to paste has this unicode
      myString = [myString stringbyappendingstring:@"\ue415"];
      txtField.text = myString;
  }
```

**EDIT** : Adding `custom image` is `not possible` in `UITextField` or either `UITextView`. Need `third party control`.

Comment: I know that each emoji has a unicode. But what I need is to copy and paste the custom image which is the like emoji.

Comment: @The_code_cracker how do you think it's possible? Try pasting a custom image into Messages.app or something else. It just wouldn't work.

Comment: I have tried all the possibilities. I dont think it will work

Answer (score 1):

Once the image is tapped you can add the this code to copy the image you want to paste.

If you are using it in keyboard, you must enable the Allow Full Access first before pasting it in the textfield.

Swift 3:

```
let pb = UIPasteboard.general
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: imageName))
pb.setData(data!, forPasteboardType: kUTTypePNG as String)
```